# Specific grouping in Tableau (Heatmap)

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to join an Excel dataset which contain (but I don't know if its possible in here) :

- The name of a course
- The ID of a problem from this course (many pb per course)
- The ID of a user that has submitted an answer for this problem from this course
- the grade that the user has obtained at this pb from this course

What I try to achieve, [it is a graph like those](https://www.google.ch/search?q=heatmap&rlz=1C5CHFA_enCH771CH771&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin6Nj8_ePXAhVEbBoKH) ! It's supposed to be call : Gradient-map, Colormap or Heat-map.

- Axe x : Every problem for each course
- Axe y : value of the grade (from 0 to 100)
- Axe z : Number of user for each Note value

So, if for the pb A of the Course A, the dispersion is like this:

- 9 users have 100
- 21 users have 80
- 40 users have 60
- 5 users have 40
- 10 users have 20
- 15 users have 0

I would like to have every value displayed on a bar and each value would be displayed by a square. Each square having a different color regarding the value represented.
So, here, 60 would be darker than any other value (since the amount of people having this grade is the greatest) and 20 would be clearer than 0, 60, 80 & 100 but darker than 40
Then, just next to this bar, the same but for the pb B & C. Then, next to it, the pb A, B & C for the course B, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move grade, name of a course, ID of a problem to Dimensions.
2. Put name of a course and ID of a problem on the columns.
3. Put grade on the rows.
4. Find a drop down list on the Marks tab and select Square.
5. Put COUNT(ID of a user) on the Color on the Marks tab

Comment: Hello @Mikhail, thx for your answer, I had already found it, but thx anyway :). Btw, Do you how I could make the null value appear ? There is a bunch of grades that have no user related. For one exam, most of the student got a 100 and a 50. But none got a 59 or a 17. So instead of a blank (and no square), do you know how I can make appear a white square (which means 0 users). Let me know if unclear